# PHP Парсер. Как сделать функцию для извлечения текста по заданной ссылке?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, парсер, curl, phpquery

Я делаю парсер на PHP который должен копировать все публикации с сайта и отображать эту информацию на моем сайте (это не кража контента, с владельцем сайта я договорился)!

Я уже написал код который копирует список публикаций на главной странице (заголовок, фото и короткий текст), теперь мне нужно парсить содержимое каждой публикации, для этого я начал парсить ссылки на все публикации (на главной странице сайта).

Сейчас мне нужно написать функцию которая будет парсить содержимое каждой публикации по этим ссылками.

Покажите пожалуйста на примере как парсить текст который находится внутри каждой ссылки!

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require 'phpQuery.php';

function print_arr($arr){
  echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, true) . '</pre>';
}

$url = 'http://lifemomentt.blogspot.com/';
$file = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

foreach($doc->find('.blog-posts .post-outer .post') as $article){
    $article = pq($article);
    $text = $article->find('.entry-title a')->html(); //парсинг заголовков на все публикации
    print_arr($text);

    $texturl = $article->find('.entry-title a')->attr('href'); //парсинг ссылок на все публикации
    echo $texturl;
}
?>
```

Comment: и в чем проблема сделать по аналогии со списком?

Comment: у меня есть ссылки на все публикации, я не знаю как парсить содержание этих ссылок (содержание я имею в виду ту информацию, которая находится когда мы перейдем по этой ссылке)

Answer (score 1):

Делаете всё так же только создайте функцию которая будет принимать URL записи и внутри функции уже запускаете парсер, дополнил ваш пример для наглядности:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require 'phpQuery.php';

//Функцию можно вынести с файла при желании
function parseArticle($url){
    $file = file_get_contents($url);
    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);
    //Тут парсите так же как и список
}

function print_arr($arr){
  echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, true) . '</pre>';
}

$url = 'http://lifemomentt.blogspot.com/';
$file = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($file);

foreach($doc->find('.blog-posts .post-outer .post') as $article){
    $article = pq($article);
    $text = $article->find('.entry-title a')->html(); //парсинг заголовков на все публикации
    print_arr($text);

    $texturl = $article->find('.entry-title a')->attr('href'); //парсинг ссылок на все публикации
    parseArticle($texturl);
}
?>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь. У меня почему-то не получается. Покажите пожалуйста на примере этого сайта http://lifemomentt.blogspot.com/
Буду очень благодарен!